# panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

Tengo esta url:

`http://www.mi.traelopaq.net/listarpaqjson.php?text1=xxx&text2=xxxxx&KEYAPI=ODUTRAS.9di23821@ldpli2skjs43&KEYPASo=OASmsjdu38IO1p29AA93JA0OD9K1221`

Si se pone en el navegador se obtiene datos, ver ejemplo:

```
 "id_tipo_envio": "1",
    "peso": "2",
    "tracking_number": "9361#######13619",
    "contenido": "test",
    "guia": "TR2210856",
    "desc_estatus_proceso": "estatus",
    "id_estatus_proceso": "3",
    "fec_creacion": "28/10/2022",
    "factura": "0",
    "trackingestatus": "99.6",
    "colorestatus": "red",
    "imagenapp": "001-hand-gesture.png",
    "id_": "10856",
    "urlfoto": "",
```

Pero en este código:

```
    func getData() (Tracking, error) {
        var rData Tracking
        
        resp, err := client.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            return Tracking{}, err
        }   
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&rData)
        if err != nil {
            return Tracking{}, err
        }   
        //fmt.Println(rData.Guia)
        return rData, nil
    }
```

Tengo el siguiente error:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

*Tracking* es una estructura.

Answer (score 0):

el problema era el siguiente:
Aunque habia definido el client:

var client *http.Client
no le asigne ningun valor, debe ser: client = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}

una vez asignado el valor: problema resuelto

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.